# What is the procedure for totally disabling HDD spin down on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, power-management, spinup

I'd like to totally disable all HDD spin down on my system that I use for music production. Is **Control panel/Power options/.../Turn off hard disk after** the place to go or are there any other settings (like some settings stored in the disk itself) that could affect this?

I have one Toshiba DT01ACA300 64MB 3TB and one older WD Caviar Black, at least one of them is affected.

Comment: [Some info on WD disks firmware spin down](http://www.storagereview.com/how_to_stop_excessive_load_cycles_on_the_western_digital_2tb_caviar_green_wd20ears_with_wdidle3)

Comment: Turning off all power saving options (like lowered voltages for idle units) in BIOS might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Toshiba drive that was causing the problem. It's not that it spins down, but it unloads the head, and it has a delay when it loads it again.

According to Toshiba technical support, the DT-series of harddrives do go into standby mode when inactive. They also state that "this cannot be circumvented". I got a recommendation to instead look at their enterprise drives, which hasn't got this delay. However, it turns out that using `hdparm`'s `-B` and `-S` options as Hennes suggested in the comment below does prevent head parking, though these commands of course have to be sent to the drive after each power cycle. Since the computer in question is a Windows 8 system used for music production, the solution was to use a `hdparm` distribution for Windows and run it as a service at each login.

Comment: "This cannot be circumvented". Interesting. So they are weird custom drives which do not listen to the normal SATA parameters?  Did you try [hdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm)'s -B and -S options?

Comment: Description of -B and -S:
-B Query/set Advanced Power Management feature, if the drive supports it. A low value means aggressive power management and a high value means better performance. Possible settings range from values 1 through 127 (which permit spin-down), and values 128 through 254 (which do not permit spin-down). The highest degree of power management is attained with a setting of 1, and the highest I/O performance with a setting of 254. A value of 255 tells hdparm to disable Advanced Power Management altogether on the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most do).

Comment: You're correct! I tried with ``hdparm`` before posting he answer, but it didn't seem to work. However, it was a problem with ``hdparm``, and now when it's running as it should, everything works fine.